# SQL Server change default QUOTENAME character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2019 Standard.  You can use QUOTENAME without passing the character parameter, but it will use brackets.  99% of the time I want to use an apostrophe.  Is there a way to change the default character without having to pass it every time?

Thank you.

Comment: `99% of the time I want to use an apostrophe` - are you using `quotename` where you should be using `sp_executesql` with parameters?

Comment: I question that too. Whilst single quoted identifiers can be used in some limited situations you shouldn't use them. What use case requires this? The answer is "no" anyway

Comment: Please show code where you would be using this. It's pretty rare that you *have* to use `''` quotes rather than `[]`, the only cases I can think of are DDL such as `CREATE LOGIN`, cases when you want to avoid parameter sniffing, and `OPENROWSET(BULK`

Comment: Just because I'm building a string doesn't mean I'm executing it.  I often use

Comment: Why else would you use `QUOTENAME`? (Or abuse it??) Please show relevant code

Answer (score -2):

I feel like the chicken who can't cross the street without his motives being questioned.  Thank you Mr. Smith.  That was the answer.

> I question that too. Whilst single quoted identifiers can be used in some limited situations you shouldn't use them. What use case requires this? The answer is "no" anyway –
> Martin Smith

Answer (score -2):

If by "apostrophe", you mean a character that looks like this (`), then the answer is "No, not directly".

If by "apostrophe", you really mean a single quote that looks like this ('), then the answer is "YES".

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(SomeStringExpression,'''')
```

If you really do mean an "apostrophe" that looks like this (`), the REPLACE can help assuming that you don't have double quotes embedded in the SomeStringExpression.

```
SELECT REPLACE(QUOTENAME(SomeStringExpression,'"'),'"','`')
```

Comment: They are asking if it is possible to configure QUOTENAME to default to single quote without them having to supply it as the second parameter, rather than defaulting to square brackets

Comment: @MartinSmith - Ah... you're right.  Thanks for the feedback, Martin.